# ExtJS global event listener not working correct

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have an application where I can click a button. If clicked the following window will be openend - with a global listener inside.

```
Ext.define('Project.view.window.Info', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

layout: 'fit',
constrain: true,


initComponent: function() {
    this.on({
        activate: function() {
            this.getEl().removeCls('window-inactive');
        },
        deactivate: function() {
            this.getEl().addCls('window-inactive');
        },
        show: function() {
            this.removeCls("x-unselectable");
        }
    });

    this.title = 'Information';
    this.items = [{
        border: false,
        autoscroll: 'true',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            name: 'moreinformation',
            border: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            bodyPadding: 20,
            html: this.updateInfo()
        }]
    }];
    this.buttons = [{
        text: 'close',
        scope: this,
        handler: this.close
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var me = this;

    Ext.on('translated', function() {
            me.down('panel[name=moreinformation]').setHtml(me.updateInfo());
    });
},

updateInfo: function() {
    return '<p>'
            + 'Update text'
            + '<br /><b>'
            + ....
            + '</p>';
}
```

});

In the application I have another button 'translate'. This button clicked some text will be translated, even in the window above.

If I toggle the translate button everything works fine. 
Now I open the 'Info'-window and close it again. If I now click the translate button then the code

```
Ext.on('translated', function() {
        me.down('panel[name=moreinformation]').setHtml(me.updateInfo());
});
```

throws an error although the Info-window is closed. 
I don't understand this. Why does the application run in this code?

Answer (score 0):

That happen, becose global event dont destroy when destroyed you componen. You must do this manually with help method [un](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.html#method-un), in `destroy` handler of you window

Comment: I have to add somthing like this:    `close: function() {
         Ext.un('translated', function() {                        this.down('panel[name=moreinformation]').setHtml(this.updateInfo());
                });
                this.destroy();
    }`

Comment: Yes. I recommend moving setHtml to another method and use it like handler for your event. and you dont need call `destroy` method. I mean you can do it all in `destroy` event, but `close` also suitable